# Maximum length of array with character

Tags: ada

I'm trying to type a word into my program where the limit is 16 characters. The problem is I have to type exactly 16 characters to proceed to the next step in my program. I want to be able to type less than 16 characters. Here is a part the code.

**Edit**: I am still a bit confused though. I'm not using a string; I'm using an array filled with characters, and I've added the declaration of `SextonTecken_Type`. I did some changes, but i still have the same problem. I can't type a shorter word to get forward.

```
type SextonTecken_Type is
    array (1..16) of Character;

procedure Gett(A: out SextonTecken_Type; N: in Integer) is      
begin
    Put("Type a string (max. 16 characters): ");  
    for I in 1..16 loop
        Get(A(I));
        if N=16 then
            Skip_Line;
        end if;
    end loop;
end Gett;
```

Answer (score 4):

From [`Ada.Text_IO`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html), use [`Get_Line`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-7.html); the `Last` parameter will contain "the index value such that `Item(Last)` is the last character assigned."

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
…
Line : String (1 .. 16);
Last : Natural;
…
Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line (Line, Last);
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Line(1 .. Last));
```

Addendum:

> I'm using an array filled with characters.

I'd still use `Get_Line` for convenience  in collecting the characters. Like [`String`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6-3.html), your type `SextonTecken_Type` is an array of elements of type `Character`. You can copy the elements from one array to another:

```
type SextonTecken_Type is array (1..16) of Character;
Buffer : SextonTecken_Type;
…
for I in 1 .. Last loop
    Buffer(I) := Line(I);
end loop;
```

Alternatively, make `SextonTecken_Type` a `subtype` of `String` and use [assignment](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-2.html#I3147):

```
subtype SextonTecken_Type is String (1 .. 16);
Buffer : SextonTecken_Type;
…
Buffer(1 .. Last) := Line(1 .. Last);
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Buffer(1 .. Last));
```

Comment: A `String` **is**, by definition, an array of `Character`; therefore, I'd think you can just do a type conversion between a `String` and a `SextonTecken_Type` as long as the `String` has length 16 (otherwise you get a `Constraint_Error` at runtime) instead of copying each element.

Comment: @ajb As long as the element types and the base of the index type is the same, you can convert through an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could change things like so:

```
-- Normal subtype indexing; requires SextonTecken_Type to be incompatible w/ String.
subtype Index_Range is Positive range 1..16;
type SextonTecken_Type is array (Index_Range range <>) of Character;
```

or

```
-- Ada 2012 style dynamic predicate; subtype compatible w/ String.
subtype SextonTecken_Type is String
with Dynamic_Predicate => SextonTecken_Type'Length <= 16;
```

And that would ensure that the string `SextonTecken_Type` is 16 or less in length.